# Extract tick params from matplotlib `ax` object

Tags: python, unit-testing, matplotlib, formatting

I want to be able to identify if tick marks have been set to 'off' using `ax.tick_params`.  Is there a way to inspect the `ax` object to see whether they have been turned off or not?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)


ax.tick_params(
    axis='both',  
    which='both',      

    bottom='off',     
    top='off',         
    left='off',
    right='off') 

# This is essentially what I want to be able to do
assert ax.xticks == 'off'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over ticks for every axis, you may use this code

```
print "Major ticks of y axis"                                              
for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    print tick.tick1On, tick.tick2On, tick.gridOn                                        
print "Minor ticks of y axis"
for tick in ax.yaxis.get_minor_ticks():
    print tick.tick1On, tick.tick2On, tick.gridOn
```

To navigate over ticks for x axis, f.e., just replace

```
ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
```

by

```
ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
```

About publicly accessible attributes of a Tick object read here: http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Tick

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. How do you do this with newer matplotlib versions?